# Java.Dynamic method return type

Tags: java

I am new in java I use GSon json parser.I have a class that send and receive json data from server.
To parse json response a do that:

```
strResult = new String(readBytes());
JsonIspResponse<JsonIspUtmInfo> res2;
Type type = (Type) new TypeToken<JsonIspResponse<JsonIspUtmInfo>>() {}.getType();
res2 = gs.fromJson(strResult, type);
```

Like in GSON docs...

I need to make a method(getResponse) that can do this:

```
JsonIspResponse<JsonIspUtmInfo> res2 = getResponse(request, JsonIspResponse<JsonIspUtmInfo>);
```

How can i do this

Comment: What type is `request`? Note also that `JsonIspResponse<JsonIspUtmInfo>` would not be a valid argument.

Comment: request is a just a class, and it is always the same.I know that it  would not be a valid argument. I mean, it must specify the desired type of the return value, but a dont know how to do it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't test it right now, but try something along these lines:

```
T getResponse(String request, TypeToken<T> typeToken) {
    return (T) gs.fromJson(request, (Type) typeToken.getType());
}

// Usage
JsonIspResponse<JsonIspUtmInfo> res2 = getResponse(request, 
    new TypeToken<JsonIspResponse<JsonIspUtmInfo>>() {});
```

Answer (score 0):

You are taking a complex way.
Use

```
JSONObject mJSONData = new JSONObject();
```

Take the values one by one like this:

```
data = mJSONData.optJSONObject("JSON_OBJECT_NAME");
```

Comment: i have many types of return data, and write rules for everyone, is not pretty